# What is economic nowcasting?

Tags: reference-request, forecasting, prediction

I am looking for a short review article on "economic nowcasting". Is there something recommended for someone interested in data science?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

"[Nowcasting](https://ideas.repec.org/p/eca/wpaper/2013-57648.html)" by Banbura, Marta; Giannone, Domenico; Reichlin, Lucrezia (2010).

Main body is 22 pages long. From the introduction of the paper:

> Economists have imperfect knowledge of the present state of the economy and even of the
> recent past. Many key statistics are released with a long delay and they are subsequently
> revised. As a consequence, unlike weather forecasters, who know what is the weather today
> and only have to predict the weather tomorrow, economists have to forecast the present and
> even the recent past. The problem of predicting the present, the very near future and the very
> recent past is labelled as nowcasting and is the subject of this paper.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Do you know of any other references with particular emphasis on links to data science?

Comment: @apkg Data science is a very broad category. You could try searching google scholar with some clever (and narrow) keywords.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will investigate.